Fill radial hole with triangles
How can I fill a hole like this? Without extruding? Can fill tool do this?


Why don't you want to extrude? - In Vertex mode, select your ring of verts with Alt, then E > S. Scale inwards then use M >Merge at Center, Only takes a few seconds...

Uploading animated Gifs seems to have stopped working again otherwise I'd have posted an answer using one.

I thought I saw a tool that can fill the hole like this automatically...But I'm not sure, I may be incorrect.

There's the Face > Grid Fill tool but that won't fill it radially. Anyway the way I suggested above only takes seconds to do. - Alt-click to select the loop of verts. S then E and scale inwards. Then M > Merge at Center. Job done.
